# Ink Sapo topbar meaning in Ink Toolkit

Tags: html, css, ink.sapo.pt

What is the topbar id in Ink Sapo UI Toolkit? It's nowhere in the documentation. Does it simply centers the menu? What does it actually do? Does anybody knows?

```
<div id="topbar">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

topbar is undocumented but it acts much like bootstraps or foundation.